# Running a script on another html page without refreshing

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, facebook, perl

I'm trying to implement a notification system similar to Facebook's in that it will have a little icon in the header that when pressed, will drop down a div that has a bunch of the user's notifications sorted in a table. I want to then have the individual notifications to be marked as "read" on hover along with a "time_created" timestamp inserted into the database for that notification. Every notification on the table has its individual "notice_id". I'm using Perl on my page and lets call it main.html.

I want to create another "readon.html" page that its sole purpose is to mark the notification as read since I have the individual notice_ids. I want to implement this where as soon as I hover over the notification in the drop down box in the header of the main.html it will perform these tasks without reloading the page.

Is this possible? Or something similar? If so what should I look into and can you push me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How comfortable are you with jQuery and its AJAX implementation?

Sounds like you need `jQuery.post()` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

`<div class="notification unread" data-noticeid="123">Lorem ipsum</div>`

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.notification.unread', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('unread');
    var notice_id = $(this).data('noticeid');
    $.post('readon.html', {notice_id: notice_id});
});
```

Your Perl script at readon.html will then grab the `notice_id` and use the current server time to mark it as "read" on the backend.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, its exactly what I was looking for. I'm pretty new to Perl, kQuery and AJAX tbh. On my "readon.html" would the script need to be something that runs automatically and would I need to redirect it back to the current page or anything like that? How does the process on the readon.html page work.

Comment: On readon.html, your Perl script will need to read the value of POST variable `notice_id` (something like `$CGI->param('notice_id')`) containing an integer value (make sure you sanitize the value to prevent SQL injections). The readon.html need not output/return/redirect any data (no HTML/CSS or anything) back to main.html. readon.html just needs to return a `200 OK` status in the header (and if you don't know what that is, don't worry about it).

Comment: Would it be possible to retrieve the notice_id without using CGI? like maybe extracted from the URL or something? Sorry, I'm still a little confused of how everything works and wether or not there will even be an url. I'd imagine it'd be something like "readon-<%= notice_id %>?

Comment: You will need to use Perl/CGI to grab the `notice_id` using either GET or POST method, then insert that into the database.